# Angular 2 + SystemJS + TypeScript: which module format to target?

Tags: typescript, angular, systemjs

TypeScript can output .js in a number of module formats - CommonJS, System, ES 2015, etc.

Which is the most appropriate target for the application modules when using the [SystemJS](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs) loader? What I've found:

- Angular 2 itself seems to be targeting CommonJS [(source)](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4278), because it's smaller and enables workflows with WebPack. But if WebPack is not used, it the best choice for System.JS?
- The Angular 2 [Quick Start](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html#!#devenv) uses CommonJS.

Size is an obvious advantage for CommonJS, but is it the only consideration? Isn't the System format more modern and future-proof (i.e. browsers one day supporting the System object natively).

What about Angular 2 server side rendering? Would that impose restrictions on the module format?